# WSO2 StreamProcessor: Is there a way to connect to MQTT using certificates in SiddhiApp

Tags: wso2, mqtt, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

Siddhi Application to be created to connect to source and sink MQTT brokers. Now, while the source is connecting it has certificate to get connected but as far as I know Siddhi IO MQTT has only username and password to be connected.
Is there a way to connect to broker using certificates where the username and password as certificate keys and also hostname is SSL enabled.

Help and guidance is needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this is not supported in siddhi-io-mqtt. Since this is open source, feel free to contribute to the code. You can see the MQTT client options here in the [code](https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-io-mqtt/blob/master/component/src/main/java/io/siddhi/extension/io/mqtt/source/MqttSource.java#L196).